# Proving two integrated results are equal

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I had to integrate $\sqrt {1+\sec (x)} $ so I  put$\sec (x)=\tan^2 (t) $ and did continue to get $2\sec^{-1}(\sqrt {sec (x)}) $ which is right as it gives same function which we want to integrate but answer given in book is $2\arcsin (\sqrt {2}\sin (x/2)) $ . How to prove these two equal or do i need to make another substitution?

Comment: $tan^2(t)$ is  never negative, while $\sec(t)$ sometimes is.  Hence your substitution only works on part of the domain.

Comment: Let $\theta=\sec^{-1}(\sqrt{\sec x})$. Setting aside issues about domain, if you manipulate this you can get $\cos^2\theta$ in terms of $\cos x$ without much trouble; from there, it's straightforward to obtain $\sin^2\theta$ and therefore $\theta$ in terms of $\sin^{-1}$.

Comment: What are you trying to show?  What "two" expression are you trying to prove are equal?

Comment: I got it thanks

Comment: @Dr.MV $arcsec (\sqrt {sec (x)})=arcsin (\sqrt {2}sin (x/2) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **NOTE:**
>
> The domain implied by the function $f(x)=\sqrt{1+\sec(x)}$ requires that $\cos(x)>0$ and $|\sqrt{2}\sin(x/2)|\le 1$

---

Note that if $y=\arcsin(\sqrt2\sin(x/2))$, then $\sin(y)=\sqrt2\sin(x/2)$ and hence

$$\cos(y)=\sqrt{1-2\sin^2(x/2)}=\sqrt{\cos(x)}$$

Finally, $\sec(y)=\sqrt{\sec(x)}\implies y=\text{arcsec}{\sqrt{\sec(x)}}$ and we are done.

Comment: Thanks it helped. I was using $arcsin (x)+arccos (x)=\pi/2$ so that pi was creating trouble

Comment: You're welcome!   My pleasure.  -Mark